# EC2 for EMR - Choosing between XLarge vs 2XLarge vs 4XLarge

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-emr

While deciding on an EC2 instance type, there are guidelines around when to choose compute-optimized (C type) vs memory-optimized (R type) vs general purpose (M type) instances (and other families as well). However, I could not find any guidance online around choosing the right size. The specs specified on the documentation do not give any indicators of differences as most of the times the sizes are proportional to the specs.

**Q: Once I've decided on a preferred instance family and generation, what factors/attributes should I consider while deciding on the size of the instance?**

**Example: Should I go for 20 c5.xlarge instances or 10 c5.2xlarge instances or 5 c5.4xlarge instances? How does choosing one against another impact my performance, etc.?**

*(Note: I'm specifically looking to make a choice for EMR, but this question could apply to any EC2 driven service (e.g. ECS) as well.)*

Comment: Your question kind of boils down to vertical scaling vs horizontal scaling. It depends on the amount of load you're processing and whether it's consistent or variable.

Comment: @neilharia7 I believe it would still be horizontal scaling when I choose any configuration but from what I understand based on your comment is that the increments while scaling up or down will get impacted. e.g. I can go for 21 c5.xlarge instances but I can never achieve an equivalent configuration with c5.2xlarge or c5.4xlarge.

Comment: In my experience, if you are clear about the amount of resources that you would definitely require, going with a higher instance type is always preferable due to lesser cost and higher availability in general.  In your example above, going with 5 c5.4xlarge would be preferred over 20 c5.xlarge instance.  The only downside that happens with the bigger instance is, in case of idle situation you pay far more than smaller instances.